# Error when importing xgboost into python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, xgboost

I am trying to install xgboost on python (2.7, using Spyder as it comes with Anaconda).

I ran:

```
conda install -c mndrake xgboost
```

and it completed successfully. But then when I try to import the module, I get:

```
import xgboost as xgb
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-10-745aa3a2d734>", line 1, in <module>
import xgboost as xgb

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
from .core import DMatrix, Booster

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\xgboost\core.py", line 112, in <module>
_LIB = _load_lib()

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-
packages\xgboost\core.py", line 106, in _load_lib
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", 
line 440, in LoadLibrary
return self._dlltype(name)

File "C:\Users\QP19\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", 
line 362, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

WindowsError: [Error 126] The specified module could not be found
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the xgboost c library installed on your computer or just the python one? because the ctypes module is looking for the c shared library files and can't find them.

Comment: @TuomasLaakkonen I assumed that conda install -c mndrake xgboost would handle any additional libraries required. Where would I get the c shared libraries?